# Ubuntu partitions on two drives

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu on two drives: / with EFI partition on a NVME disk, and a /home partition on a SATA SSD. What should I do to if I want to store some programs on the NVME boot disk as right now I can't add files to it, and is this is even a good setup? Can I create a partition in that disk for files? Or would a single default install on the NVME would be better, with some files stored in the SATA disk?

Comment: Is your NVME disk full? When you install programs on Linux they are not stored in /home. They will be somewhere on the / partition, the NVME disk in your case. You don’t get to choose where program files are stored in the same way as you do in Windows. Your setup is fine, many Linux users go for a / partition and a /home partition. You probably want / to be on your fastest device which is what you have. Files within home will be tend to be data so there is not much benefit in having that on the NVME too.

Comment: It's not full, however, I have a program that was downloaded, extracted and can be moved around and I wonder if there's a way to move it from /home to the faster disk.

Comment: Normally you would install programs from the software centre or by using a sudo apt package-name command. If you have just downloaded some random program it probably will not run unless you install it. You can move files to the / partition but remember all of that is owned by root so you have to create a directory there, such as /data and grant your user appropriate permissions. Then you will be able to save files there.

Comment: It does run, it's an executable. I tried to make a directory with mkdir, and it said 'permission denied', do I have to change permissions first, and how?

Comment: You have to use mkdir with sudo to make a folder at a place in the filesystem that belongs to root. So sudo mkdir /mikunda will make a folder immediately below / named mikunda. You can take ownership of that folder with a chown command. It’s better that you research that yourself. Search for “Linux chown examples “ on your search engine of choice

Comment: It's done, thank you very much for answers!  (I'd mark as answered, but I see no icon beside the comment to do it, only a flag)

Comment: You can answer your own question and describe what you did to fix it. After 24 hours you can mark it as accepted. That may help others in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created a folder inside / partition:

`sudo mkdir /foldername`

2. Changed folder's ownership:

`sudo chown username /foldername`